# How could I find the correct key pair given the plaintext and ciphertext

Tags: brute-force-attack

If I have a known plaintext and ciphertext pairs and 2 unknown keys of length 24 bits. (Assume encryption method is unknown)

```
9acb0442f0c5341e 035a85c5772da926
aa209b8e700e0976 f1849958b47fec38
6cb50b02afd3a30c 4e48ca11ee429960
10cd96722811a558 0a18dd10a6b31c5c
18d2fe904d088f48 f84950f2d18dc4e8
83e4f98dd04ab55f 4dc9a896a1dd3a99
36d9ff456172bfe3 ea626b82da337f24
516c42b078092a35 05d5757be9fca1e7
```

The first key encrypts the first column and the second key encrypts the result to achieve the second column. How can I find the correct key pair?

Bruteforcing 2^48 should be infeasible, so my original for loop won't work

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 16777216; i++) // 16777216 is 2^24 and i is for first key
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 16777216; j++) // j is for second key
                {
                   temp = doubleEncrypt(int i, int j, a.getPlaintext()); // store the resulting cipher text in temp
                   if(temp == a.getCiphertext() // check if what we got matches the actual cipher text
                   {
                       System.out.println("The " + val+1 + "th key pair is:");
                       printKeyPair(i, j); // if match is found print keys i, j
                   }
                }
            }
```

My idea was to double encrypt the first column until I get the second column, but I am not sure how to do this in at most 2^25 iterations.

Comment: We don't answer basic homework questions. Hint: encrypt a plaintext, e.g. `9acb0442f0c5341e` with all possible keys `i` and store the results in a dictionary. Now, how would you check (with high confidence) a guess of key `j` with a single encryption or decryption operation?

Comment: thank you I will try that